# Неограниченное количество доменов на домашнем сервере

Tags: linux, dns, proxmox, bind9

Хочу реализовать несколько проектов на домашнем сервере, но есть проблема.

На данный момент имеется 2 доменных имени domain1.ru и domain2.ru. У регистратора прописаны  по 3 записи: SOA на dns сервер регистратора, A для *. и A для корня.

На домашнем сервере стоит Proxmox, который стоит за роутером со статическим адресом, например 1.1.1.1. Можно ли средствами bind9 или какими-то другими (может DNS proxmox`а?) разрулить домены между машинами proxmox? Прочитал уже несколько статей и кроме "как bind9 настроить для локальной сети" ничего не встретил. Самое простое завернуть все домены в одну машину, а внутри разрулить апачем или хапрокси (это то что я пробовал), но проблема в том что на доменах не только web-сайты, и разрулить кастомные порты (тот же ssh) с прямым доступом из сети в конкретную тачку не представляется возможным.

Не могли бы вы подсказать возможно ли вообще поднять свой публичный DNS, что прописать у регистратора и как его настроить?

Answer (score 1):

Можно разрулить для доступа с локалки. делаешь кучу записей `

```
A 192.168.0.2 server2.domain.com
A 192.168.0.3 server3.domain.com
A 192.168.0.4 server4.domain.com
```

где отдельные айпишники каждой виртуальной машины.

Для доступа с интернета ДНСу нужны отдельные внешние адреса для каждой машины.